# Mathjax in Firefox 5

Tags: bug, status-declined, mathjax

I am running the latest version of Mozilla firefox and there seems to be some problem: The math font appears dark. It's been happening for the past two days. Before it was working fine. Below is the image:

[image]

Any idea of how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Can't reproduce this in Firefox 5 (current version) on Windows 7, so it is likely a bug specific to your OS or Firefox, not our site.

[image]

Comment: Emm.. I see, but I don't understand what went wrong

Comment: I was receiving (for the past two days) a notice that MathJax had changed somehow and a certain default was no longer the default, but that the style sheets that were being used were using the old standard. Today it's working fine. I suspect this was the source of Chandru's "problem", given the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

When MathJax fonts are defined to be a color, but are displayed in black, this almost certainly means you are receiving image fonts (rather than web-fonts).

As a first resort you should clear the browser cache and try again. After that, some things to check are:

- Are you behind a proxy that rejects OTF web-fonts?
- Have you installed STIX or MathJax fonts locally (but incorrectly)?
- Do you have a slow internet connection? This could cause the loading of web-fonts to timeout.